# Either ContentLength must be set to a non-negative number, or SendChunked set to true in order to perform the write operation

Tags: c#, soap, stream, httpwebrequest, xmldocument

Using `HttpWebRequest`, I used the following code to request a soap and get a stream:

```
XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
HttpWebRequest webRequest = ...

using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
}
```

While this is the error message:

```
Either ContentLength must be set to a non-negative number, or SendChunked set to true in order to perform the write operation when AllowWriteStreamBuffering is disabled.
```

As the above message says, I can't write to the stream because if I call the save soapEvelopeXml the application ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the error, simply enable a parameter within the HttpWebRequest object.

```
webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
```

The parameter is part of the object properties and citing from the documentation on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8)

AllowWriteStreamBuffering : Gets or sets a value that indicates whether to buffer the data sent to the Internet resource